# Sql delete thousands of rows with text file

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database that has a few tables with over 150,000 rows. I want to delete all but about 18,000.

My plan is to go through and obtain the Id of every item I need to keep. I have a list but some names might not match so I plan on manually documenting the ids that I need to keep in a text file. Is there a way I can use said text file to delete everything but the IDs in this text file? Is there a better way?

---

Backstory: I'm running a game server eq emulator and was able to acquire a list of all items in the game up the expansions I want from the game wiki. But the emulator was written years into the release so items are not in order. I need to get rid of many items on this list of ids and I need to do this in multiple tables.

I tried searching the internet for like situations and saw references to using a list to complete the task. Now my goal is generating a list of items to keep because it is a lot smaller than the items I need to remove.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do this with PhpMyAdmin. You need to write a script that reads the file and puts all the IDs into the SQL query.

Comment: You can put all the IDs into a string like `1100, 200, 301`. Then the query will be `DELETE FROM tablename WHERE id NOT IN (that string)`

Comment: Maybe rename the table(s), then use the list as a source to repopulate a new blank table.

Comment: Apologies for my ignorance but I don't know what phpmyadmin can/can't do; what prevents you from loading the text file (of ids to delete or not - either would work) into a new mysql table and delete in a single SQL command?

Answer (score 0):

Alter the table(s) to add column named something like `ToDelete`. Then you can start updating this column to target your desired rows, and can do it across potentially many steps. Finally, you can run one short DELETE query to remove every targeted row by targeting the new column in the WHERE clause.

I would also be inclined to rename or copy the tables first, to preserve the data in the existing database for quick recovery of rows anywhere you make a mistake.